# More concise way to declare high dimensional vector

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, template-meta-programming

I don't like how for example a 3 dimensional vector is called this way:

```
std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<value_type>>>
```

Not to mention if I would like to have 4 dimensional or even higher.

Is there any way to use perhaps template metaprogramming or some technique to be able to declare high dimension vector with higher readability?

For example to be able to declare an high dimensional vector like this (just an example):

```
t_vector<5, {10, 2, 2, 2, 2}, int> a;
```

and get a with capacity of [10][2][2][2][2].

Is it possible to do something like this?
Or why if not?

Comment: and what you mean by `high dimensional vector`? what functions you need?

Comment: I mean that by to be able to declare any number of layers for the vector (during compile time) with user-defined sugar syntax (like in the question). After declaring the container, I hope it has the same functionality as what it corresponds to (by std::vector).

Comment: I am rather new to template metaprogramming. I have seen how std::tuple is expanded, by I am not experienced enough to apply that to create the sugar syntax for vector that I want.

Comment: Why `vector` if you want a compile time fixed capacity?

Comment: How about The Boost Multidimensional Array Library?

Comment: Because std::vector provides many other functions (e.g. size(), push_back(), etc.) and those are not included in C-style arrays.

Comment: So you *don't* want a fixed capacity, you intend to push back.

Comment: I want to know if it is possible to do that by just adding a short snippet in the beginning of my code. For most of the time I only write short codes and is restricted to used only the standard library.

Comment: besides that, why not use a function?

Comment: @StoryTeller yes, I now figured out I didn't state it correctly. I just want a short syntax that would expand itself to the ordinary std::vector, with all the dynamic capabilities.

Comment: @appleapple what would the parameters look like? As long as it is short to call, it solves my problem. Although I am curious if it is possible to do with template.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From you example, what you need is `std::array` instead of `std::vector`, since the latter doesn't have fixed length.

You can just use recursion to specialize the template:

```
template<class T, size_t... Ns> struct foo;

template<class T, size_t N0, size_t... Ns>
struct foo<T, N0, Ns...> {
    using type = std::array<typename foo<T, Ns...>::type, N0>;
};

template<class T>
struct foo<T> {
    using type = T;
};

template<class T, size_t... Ns>
using multiarray_t = typename foo<T, Ns...>::type;

static_assert(
        std::is_same_v<
            multiarray_t<int, 3, 2, 5>,
            std::array<std::array<std::array<int, 5>, 2>, 3>
            >
        );
```

**EDIT:**

If you want to init a `std::vector` with given size, the similar approach still applies:

```
template<class T, size_t... Ns> struct vec_builder;
template<class T, size_t N0, size_t... Ns>
struct vec_builder<T, N0, Ns...> {
    using type = std::vector<
        typename vec_builder<T, Ns...>::type>;
    static type build() {
        return type(N0, vec_builder<T, Ns...>::build());
    }
};
template<class T>
struct vec_builder<T> {
    using type = T;
    static type build() { return {}; }
};

int main() {
    auto vec = vec_builder<int, 3, 2, 5>::build();
    static_assert(
            std::is_same_v<
            decltype(vec),std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<int>>>
            >);
    assert(vec.size() == 3);
    assert(vec[0].size() == 2);
    assert(vec[1][0].size() == 5);
}
```

Comment: Great! For most cases this solves my problem. But is it possible to apply the similar approach to std::vector and be able to dynamically resize afterwards?

Comment: @zetta yes it is possible, keep in mind that you might invalidate iterators if you resize the vectors

Comment: @zetta if you dynamically resize, it is *very* easy to end up with *different sizes* among elements of the same dimension. It's probably better to store everything in a 1D vector, and have a collection of dimension sizes

Comment: What's a better solution if I promise I won't resize, but want to pass it to a function that reads std::vector as its parameter?

Comment: @zetta `std::vector<` What `>`? If you have a function that's defined for a deeply nested vector, that's what you have to pass

Comment: @Caleth yes, but if I take the multiarray approach, is it possible to convert to std::vector<deeply_nested_vectors> with the same dimensions?

Comment: @zetta It's similar, see edit. But if you want to do complicated operations on it, it'd be better to use a dedicated library, like `Eigen`.

Comment: I'd be tempted to move `typename vec_builder<T, Ns...>::type` into an alias, e.g. `template<class T, size_t... Ns> using vec_builder_t = typename vec_builder<T, Ns...>::type;`

Answer (score 0):

You could use a typedef which just creates an alias for a type e.g.

```
typedef std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<int>>> iVector3d;
```

From now on you just use iVector3d instead of that big ugly thing and C++ will literally replace iVectord3 with the actual definition when you run the code so nothing else changes.

The draw back to this is that you have to specify the type, like as I've done with the int there. But the plus is that its super easy to use compared to templates.

Comment: `template <typename T>
using Vector3d = std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<T>>>` to be generic (since C++11).

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think the solution from https://stackoverflow.com/users/8605791/llllllllll above **does not** solve the main case to `std::vector`.

As once you've tried to declare something like 'vec_builder<int, n, m>::build()', where the `n` or `m` is actually **variable** instead of **constant**.

Just try this (requires `C++17` or higher):

```cpp
template<class T, class... Args> auto multivector(size_t n, Args&&... args) {
  if constexpr (sizeof...(args) == 1) {
    return std::vector<T>(n, args...);
  } else {
    return std::vector(n, multivector<T>(args...));
  }
}
```

- usage: `auto g = multivector<long long>(n, m, 0);`
- equivalent: `std::vector g(n std::vector<long long>(m));`

btw this is my first post to stackoverflow... XD